# How do I revert to the pathbar after the address bar is visible in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

When using Nautilus you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to display the addressbar. How do you revert back to the pathbar? Is there a shortcut key?